# Unable to implement upper_bound() properly

Tags: c++, binary-search

I struggle a lot with binary search implementations, especially

- how to choose high and low (or `r` and `l`)
- whether to put equality sign in while loop condition or not
- whether to update `r=mid` or `r=mid-1`

I was trying to implement `upper_bound` from `STL`, but couldn't get the correct answer. Here is my code.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<climits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n+2);
    // adding 0 in front to avoid out of bounds error 
    // when looking for a[m-1]
    a[0]=0;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    // adding a big element at the end to return that index
    // when required element is greater than all elements
    a[n]=INT_MAX;

    // q queries for testing purposes
    int q;
    cin >> q;
    while(q--){
        // we return m-1 at the end, so l and r capture 
        // all possible outputs, inclusive bounds
        int l=1, r=n+1, m;
        int val;
        cin >> val;

        // always confused whether to put in 
        // the equality sign or not
        while(l<=r){
            m=(l+r)/2;
            // break when the required element is found
            if(a[m]>val && val>=a[m-1])
                break;
            else if(val>a[m])
                l=m+1;
            else
                r=m-1;
        } 
        cout << m-1 << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample input for testing:

```
7
3 6 8 10 11 14 22
6
0 10 1 3 15 28
```

Expected output if I had used upper_bound from STL:

```
0 4 0 1 6 8
```

Got output for my implementation

```
0 2 0 1 6 6
```

I am getting the wrong output and I can't figure out why. Any simplifications I could keep in mind to avoid such implementation errors or to ease my understanding of how to write code for binary search?

Comment: Why the "c" tag?

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: In a comment you give an expected output. For what input? The output does not look like a sorted version of any input. So what is the logic of the desired output?

Comment: @Yunnosch the expected output is for the input I've provided. There are 2 arrays, first one being the sorted array to binary search on, and the second one is for queries. I have mentioned everything in my code.

Comment: The expected output does not look like a sorted version of any input. So what is the logic of the desired output?

Comment: the output is not supposed to be sorted. These are the indices that upper_bound would return for the respective queries.

Comment: There is no output posted in the question, @Yunnosch. That's all input. The first number indicates the sorted sequence length, the second line is that sequence, the third line is the number of queries to perform, and the final line is the numbers for each query to test

Comment: @WhozCraig So what do you think this is `// expected output 
    // 0 4 0 1 6 8
    // got output
    // 0 2 0 1 6 6` ?  (I just noticed that it also has the produced output...)

Comment: @Yunnosch not going to lie; I stopped reading code as soon as I saw the search implementation, and reeled at the opposition to 0-based indexing.

Comment: @WhozCraig I am sorry. I cannot wrap my head around the normal binary search implementations. I tried to make it easier for myself.

Comment: The question has successfully confused more than one not exactly inexperienced user into missing relevant information. Please consider improving for clarity. Here is helpful information: [ask], https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @KaranSingh Believe me, 1-basing the indexing doesn't make it easier. It actually makes it harder. Ideally, an iterator-based approach would be ideal, but index-based is pretty close if you wrap your head around it.

Answer (score 5):

To design correct binary search function, don't try to guess the solution, it's hard to get it right. Use the method of loop invariants. Suppose, we want to implement `upper_bound` from the Standard library:

```
template<class It, typename T>
It upper_bound(It first, It last, const T& value);
```

According to the [specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) of `upper_bound`, we are looking for the transition point `pt`, such that in the range `[first, pt)` all elements have values `<= value`, and in the range `[pt, last)` all elements have values `> value`.

Let's introduce two iterators (pointers) `left` and `right` with the loop invariants:

- in the range `[first, left)` all elements have values `<= value`,
- in the range `[right, last)` all elements have values `> value`.

These ranges represent elements examined so far. Initially, `left = first`, and `right = last`, so both ranges are empty. At each iteration one of them is expanded. Finally, `left = right`, so the whole range `[first, last)` is now examined. From the definitions above, it follows that `pt = right`.

The following algorithm implements this idea:

```
template<class It, class T>
It upper_bound(It first, It last, const T& value) {
    auto left  = first;
    auto right = last;

    while (left < right) {
        const auto mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        if (*mid <= value)        // update left,  i.e. expand [first, left)
            left = mid + 1;
        else                      // update right, i.e. expand [right, last)
            right = mid;
    }

    return right;
}
```

Note that we're dealing with half-open ranges. We want to include `mid` into one of the expanded ranges. That's why we set `left`, the right (excluded) boundary, to `mid + 1`, but we set `right`, the left (included) boundary, to `mid`.

All these can be easily rewritten in terms of indices and is left as a simple exercise.

Comment: thank you, my concept about it a lot clearer now. One thing I still don't understand, is what to return after the search is complete. In your instance, why have we returned right and not left?

Comment: @KaranSingh, after the loop, `left` is equal to `right`. You can return `left` if you want. :)